# How to setup jsreport MVC to run as webserver not as utility?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, server, jsreport

I want to use jsreport in webserver mode instead of utility mode with ASP.NET MVC. Utility mode is to use the command line arguments and server mode to start the binary as web server and communicate with it using http protocol.

This is shown on jsreport.net, but there is no example for CustomFilter version used in MVC.

```
var rs = new LocalReporting().UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary()).AsWebServer().Create();
await rs.StartAsync();
var report = await rs.RenderAsync(...);
await rs.KillAsync();
```

So I want to use it as CustomFilter solution in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to rewrite RegisterGlobalFilters method to use jsreport as webserver:

```
public static ILocalWebServerReportingService RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); 

  var rs = new LocalReporting()
    .Configure(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.BaseUrlAsWorkingDirectory();
      return cfg;
    })
    .UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
    .AsWebServer()
    .Create();

  rs.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  filters.Add(new JsReportFilterAttribute(rs));

  return rs;
}
```

and then we need to use referenced reporting service to stop on application end in Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  private ILocalWebServerReportingService reportingService;

  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    ...
    reportingService = FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    ...
  }

  protected void Application_End()
  {
    reportingService.KillAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
}
```